# KeyError issue on github gist script (converting whatsapp export to slack import)

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this script (no longer maintained): https://gist.github.com/onekiloparsec/a7df8dd1f2babd9740e8

And I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatsapp2slack.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "whatsapp2slack.py", line 47, in main
    output_elements["content"] += "\n"+line.strip()
KeyError: 'content'
```

Any idea what the problem could be? Would it help if I initialised this output_elements variable in some way? Or is the problem different? Sorry, total noob to python.

Comment: As mentioned,
You don't have that key 'content' in the dict.
Try printing ```output_elements```.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialized 'content' key hence you are recieving an error.

You can initialize it `output_elements = {'content':''}`

Or use `defaultdict` with the default value required in your case it is str:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output_elements = defaultdict(str)

with open(output_file.name, 'w') as outfile:    

    for line in input_lines:
        try:
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[:19], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        except ValueError:
            # We cannot find a date, it's a continuation of a line, most probably...
            output_elements["content"] += "\n"+line.strip()
```

Comment: I tried both methods but it failed. 
Method 1 error: `File "whatsapp2slack.py", line 81, in main
    new_line = '{0} {1} @{2} "{3}"'.format(output_elements["date"].timestamp(), channel_name, output_elements["username"], output_elements["content"])
KeyError: 'date'`
How do I initialise a date object?
Method 2 failed because it initialised it as a string, but there is also a date in the object being parsed.

Comment: You are getting another error in a diff line.
Though your main question was answered.

Comment: Understand. Unable to verify if it solved the problem as it still doesn't compile. I'll try another question and if that solved the second issue i'll mark this answer correct. for now, unable to assess.

Comment: 'How do I initialise a date object? Method 2 failed because it initialised it as a string'
So use a diff var.
```elem_date = dt```

Then:
```new_line = '{0} {1} @{2} "{3}"'.format(elem_date.timestamp(), channel_name, output_elements["username"], output_elements["content"])```

Comment: Here is a fixed ver:
https://gist.github.com/DavidMeu/da49f6f2dd4f861413267f8840b908ed

Comment: Thanks so much for the gist! 
Unfortunately I still got `File "whatsapp2slack.py", line 78, in main
    new_line = '{0} {1} @{2} "{3}"'.format(elem_date.timestamp(), channel_name, output_elements["username"], output_elements["content"])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'elem_date' referenced before assignment` as an error. Is this a Py2.7 issue?

Comment: Probably need to init elem_date,
updated gist.
'Is this a Py2.7 issue?' no

Comment: I'm so sorry - this is frustrating. It's going back to a similar error I saw previously:
`File "whatsapp2slack.py", line 79, in main
    new_line = '{0} {1} @{2} "{3}"'.format(elem_date.timestamp(), channel_name, output_elements["username"], output_elements["content"])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`